# git config --list Find one more user.naemail=xb1 how to delete user.naemail?

Tags: git

I use:

```
git config --list
```

And I want to find one more `user.naemail=xb1` and delete it.

Here is the output of the command:

````
$ git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
credential.helper=manager
user.email=xxx@163.com
user.name=xxx
user.naemail=xb1```
````

Answer (score 0):

The general command is [`git config --unset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt---unset)

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git config --unset user.naemail
```

Check *where* the setting comes from with:

```
git config -l --show-origin
```

If it is from ~/.gitconfig, you would need to do:

```
git config --global --unset user.naemail
```